Pandas: Sort and plot values with 2 columns
I met some difficulties because I'm a real beginners with Algo and code. I've got a set of data that I want to analyze.
My objective is to have an average value of the measurement depending of the name.
I have a dataframe with two columns:



Name
Measurement value




PN1
5.4


PN2
6.5


PN3
9.6


PN2
5.4


PN4
7.4


PN2
5.4


...
...


...
...



What I want to obtain is something like that: Name with average value measurement by name :



Name
AVG Measurement value




PN1
5.4


PN2
6.5


PN3
9.6


PN4
5.4



I'm a beginners in Pandas so I need help.
I've no idea how to proceed

You can use groupby():
import pandas as pd

D = {
    'Name': ['PN1', 'PN2', 'PN3', 'PN2', 'PN4', 'PN2'],
    'Measurement value': [5.4, 6.5, 9.6, 5.4, 7.4, 5.4]
}


df = pd.DataFrame(D)

res = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False).mean()
res.columns = ['Name', 'AVG Measurement value']

print(res)


Prints
  Name  AVG Measurement value
0  PN1               5.400000
1  PN2               5.766667
2  PN3               9.600000
3  PN4               7.400000



For plotting, you can use matplotlib:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


D = {
    'Name': ['PN1', 'PN2', 'PN3', 'PN2', 'PN4', 'PN2'],
    'Measurement value': [5.4, 6.5, 9.6, 5.4, 7.4, 5.4]
}


df = pd.DataFrame(D)


res = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False).mean()
res.columns = ['Name', 'AVG Measurement value']


plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
plt.bar(res['Name'], res['AVG Measurement value'], color='black')
plt.xlabel('Name')
plt.ylabel('AVG')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()





Thanks a lot for your reactivity ! It's ok for me!
